# To validate the values by conditional relationship of another column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to validate whether the **value** of each row follow the **rule** or not. Here's how the original data and rule look like.

[image]

Text version:

```
id  Item    value   Rule
001 A   3   A<B<C>D>E
002 B   5   
003 C   9   
004 D   7   
005 E   1   
006 F   6   F<G<H>I>J
007 G   8   
008 H   10  
009 I   9   
010 J   7   
011 K   2   K<L<M>N>O
012 L   1   
013 M   7   
014 N   5   
015 O   4
```

Then I created two columns, category and sub_category, to express the rule so that I can write a function to check its status. Under each category, the values responded to the sub_category will follow the rule, H>M>L.

[image]

Is there any beauty ways to achieve it? Thanks

The expected result will be:

[image]

** ID:012 doesn't follow the rule that the value needs to be smaller than the maximum of the values of ID:011 and ID:015. So, the result will return fail for this category.

Comment: Please update your post with the text version of your first image. If you load your file in a dataframe, you can use `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: For `id001` you want to know if value (A, 3) > (L, 1), that's right? If yes I don't understand why `id002` (B, 5) > (M, 7) pass the test?

Comment: U can learn from the first table that it's the value to validate whether following the rule from sub_category under each of category. So, (A,B,C,D,E) belongs to a group that can't compare with the value(L,1) from another group(K, l, M, N, O).